# Rails mongoid ordered embeds_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have document User and I want to store ordered stack of another users in this document. Example structure of User document:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("parentID"),
  "stack": [
    { "_id": ObjectID("ChildId2"), position: 1 },
    { "_id": ObjectID("ChildId3"), position: 2 },
    { "_id": ObjectID("ChildId1"), position: 3 }
  ]
}
```

How can I do this with Mongoid? Generally I want to get ordered (by adding or by field) embeds_many association.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you need here but you can specify the order of embedded documents using the `order` option on the association. For example:

```
embeds_many :stack, :order => :position.asc
```

will ensure that `user.stack` returns the objects on the stack ordered by position.